# Is NULL necessary?

Tags: sql-server, null, sql-update, alter

Is NULL or NOT NULL necessary for Adding a column in SQL Server? (If you are going to run UPDATE statement after)

I tested without it locally, and it seems to work fine both in SQL and on the website; but I wanted to make sure before running release/production.

I looked up some other articles, including microsoft website. Some show it with, some without. SO articles say some benefits of NULL, like if you have information that may be added later. But assuming I am going to run UPDATE to add values after, will it matter?

I am guessing it does not matter from what I've tested and read.

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyTable] ADD NewColumn varchar(150);
UPDATE [dbo].[MyTable] SET NewColumn ='Math' WHERE ID = 1
UPDATE [dbo].[MyTable] SET NewColumn ='Science' WHERE ID = 2
```

Comment: The question isn't when you insert or update data, the question is whether it's logically correct for the entity you model in a table to have a value of `NULL` in one of its attributes modeled as a column. If and only if it isn't, the column should be `NOT NULL`. But as you didn't tell what you're trying to model, you won't get much useful answers to that question I'm afraid.

Comment: To clarify, the table already has rows with data, I am just adding a new column and afterwards adding data to the *new* column in each row. I was not aware, but perhaps a before/after diagram may have been helpful on my part.

Comment: Ah, right, my mistake!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can skip it, and by default the column will be created as NULL. However it is more legible if you indicate it explicitly.

Keep in mind that if your table already has data, you CANNOT add the column as NOT NULL. For this, you should firstly add the column as NULL, then UPDATE the values with non-null valid data and then alter column to NOT NULL.

Edit: Assuming the default behavior of the sql server when adding columns.

Comment: Don't assume - the setting [ANSI_NULL_DFLT_ON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-ansi-null-dflt-on-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) controls this.

Comment: You can add the column as NOT NULL if you also simultaneously set a DEFAULT value (but that default will apply to every row and, depending on the version of SQL Server, will be a blocking, size-of-data operation).

Comment: @SMor You are right. My answer applies only to the default behavior of sql server.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to write it, when you skip it column will be created as 'NULL'.
Following statements are equal:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyTable] ADD NewColumn varchar(150);
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyTable] ADD NewColumn varchar(150) NULL;
```

If you want to add a column and DB engine should guarantee you that this new column will be always populated you can add a NOT NULL column with a default value.
Other option will be to change the column to NOT NULL after the update.

Answer (score 0):

I'd make sure you have something declarative. And if you are setting as "not null," be sure you have a default value or use can suffer LOTS of data loss if data previously exists. It makes me nervous because this an ALTER vs a CREATE.